# Cannot assign "u'2'": "CartItem.product" must be a "Product" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to allow the customer to add an item (CartItem) to their cart. The CartItem is linked to my Products model via ForeignKey. I've created a list of products through the admin.

I'm able to get the form (AddItemForm) to populate on the .html page and show the list of products available. But when I select an item, choose the quantity and hit 'Add Item', I get the following error:

Cannot assign "u'2'": "CartItem.product" must be a "Product" instance

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

models.py

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.title
```

views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):       

    request.session.set_expiry(120000)

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']                 
    except:

        new_cart = Cart()       # creates brand new instance
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id    # sets cart_id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)  # use the cart with the 'id' of the_id
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    form = AddItemForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":

        qty = request.POST['quantity']
        product = request.POST['product']

        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)
        cart_item.quantity = qty

        cart_item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('cart')))

    context = {

        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, 'create_cart.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Cart, CartItem

from products.models import Product

class AddItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ["product", "quantity"]
```

.html

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}



<form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.product }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.quantity }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add Item" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies at that line:

```
cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)
```

The `create` method expects `product` to be a `Product` instance, you are passing a string (`u'2'`).

Use `product_id` instead of `product`:

```
product_id = int(request.POST['product'])
cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product_id=product_id)
```

This solves the code as it is but you should use the `AddItemForm` instead of creating the `CartItem` directly from the POST data:

```
form = AddItemForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()  # Takes care of saving the cart item to the DB.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```